# Javascript - XMLHttpRequest, result are always undefined

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to test if the xml file have the tag "`<group>`"

```
var xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "xmlfile.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
xml = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement; 

var thegroup = xml.getElementsByTagName('group')[0];
if (!group) {
    alert('No <group> in the XML: ' + xml);
    return;
} else {
    alert(xml + 'have a <group> tag');
}
```

Even if my xml file have the tag "`<group>`" the result is always negative, and the variable "`thegroup`" is undefined.

"`xml`" give me "[object Element]"

Where is my mistake?

PS: I'm only interested in webkit, I don't care about IE, Opera or Firefox for now.

EDIT : HERE IS MY ACTUAL CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>xmltest</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function init() {

var xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "xmlfile.xml");
xmlhttp.send(null);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction;

function callbackFunction(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
     xml = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement; 
    var group = xml.getElementsByTagName('group')[0];
    console.debug(xml)
    if (!group) {
      alert('No <group> in the XML: ' + xml);
      return;
    } else {
      alert(xml + 'have a <group> tag');
    }
  }
}

};

</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init();">

</body>
</html>
```

and my xmlfile.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<group type="vertical">
<name>name</name>
<title>title</title>
</group>
```

At this point the alert is triggered saying :
No `<group>` in the XML: [object Element]

So maybe my problem is just on the way I try to find the `<group>` tag ?

Comment: Abstract away the AJAX. Make the input to your testcase a hard-coded string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest is asynchronous, it doesn't work that way. When you use `xmlhttp.send(null);` you have to define  callback function that will be executed when the server responds with the data, otherwise you are trying to access empty data.
The code would look something like this:

```
var xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "xmlfile.xml");
xmlhttp.send(null);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction;



function callbackFunction(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
     xml = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement; 
    var thegroup = xml.getElementsByTagName('group')[0];
    if (!group) {
      alert('No <group> in the XML: ' + xml);
      return;
    } else {
      alert(xml + 'have a <group> tag');
    }
  }
}
```

this way, you are using `onReadyStateChange` to tell the browser to run `callbackFunction` everytime the server sends back a response. It tests for the `readyState` to be 4 which means that the request has been completely served.

Comment: Thanks but I got "Uncaught ReferenceError: xml is not defined" for xml.getElementsByTagName('group')[0]; ...

Comment: -1: No, this is a synchronous request. See his third argument to `.open`. And yours, incidentally; `onreadystatechange` won't even be invoked.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I edited the answer so to move the line xml = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement; to inside the if clause in the callback

Comment: You are right @lightness, i didn' see that. So the answer is really 'group' vs 'thegroup' as you  answered, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: if I put an alert alert(thegroup); right after "var thegroup = xml.getElementsByTagName('group')[0];" I get "thegroup is not defined"

Comment: That's strange. Meanwhile i edited the xmlhttp.open line so the request can be asynchronous (you should always avoid sync requests as good practise). Try a console.debug(xml) after declaring that var and tell me what you see in the console

Comment: console.debug(xml) show me the xml file content in the console

Comment: So in that way xml.getElementsByTagName should give you an array, i think. That's weird

Comment: How can I make a iterative call every N second to the Get request ? without refreshing the page. I am able to parse the data and print it to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var thegroup = xml.getElementsByTagName('group')[0];
> if (!group) {
>     alert('No <group> in the XML: ' + xml);
>     return;
> } else {
>     alert(xml + 'have a <group> tag');
> }
> ```

What is `group`? Did you mean `thegroup`?

Comment: group is the xml tag '<group>Lorem</group>' in xmlfile.xml that I want to test.
I can change the variable 'thegroup' to 'group' it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Julian: It _does_ change something: it'll mean that you're not testing something that doesn't exist in your `if` condition.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I have to test on the variable name, not the tag name. so the correct variable name should be 'group' not 'thegroup'. But it still doesn't change anything, because 'group' is still undefined if I put an alert before the if

Comment: @Julian: No, the variable name is `thegroup`. When you do `var`, you're assigning to `thegroup`. But then in the `if` you're checking on `group`, which does not exist. You meant to write `if (!thegroup)`