# Node.js with ExpressJS error: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, requirejs

Running node.js v0.10.2 and express v3.1.1 (latest at this time) and getting this error:

```
/root/dmr-addresses/node_modules/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js:10
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.withCredentials = false;
                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
  at create (/root/dmr-addresses/node_modules/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js:10:26)
  at /root/dmr-addresses/node_modules/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js:9503:18
  at Object.<anonymous> (/root/dmr-addresses/node_modules/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js:9505:2)
  at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
  at require (module.js:378:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/root/dmr-addresses/address/log.js:1:71)
```

line 1 of log.js is:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

I've tried running `npm install jquery` but it has not fixed the problem.

Comment: Is this on Windows or Linux? Do you have the log from the npm install? It looks like XMLHttpRequest is not a member of window. I am not sure jQuery adds that.

Comment: Linux, log: https://gist.github.com/thomasjmwb/5296136

Comment: I was only asking because the npm install for jQuery is problematic on Windows. Are you sure window.XMLHttpRequest is a part of jQuery? I'm not extremely well versed, but I don't recall that.

Comment: I'm not sure, I started to get this error after upgrading to the most recent version of node though. I've also made sure try the answers to this question but have not had any luck yet.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979531/errors-using-jquery-with-node-js

Comment: Looks like the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063058/keep-getting-error-for-browserless-jquery-in-node

Comment: Have you tried downgrading your node and run the same code? Are you able to run that without any modification? Please let us know that..

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni I've just finished downgrading to v0.8.21 and am getting the same error..
@ BenEvans I am installing this on a linux server so I don't think the windows issue is a problem here

Comment: Have you looked at either of these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363212/window-xmlhttprequest-is-undefined-in-ie7-ie8     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151834/javascript-xmlhttprequest-result-are-always-undefined

Comment: @ThomasW-B Then please consider changing the title of your question. since it contains "after upgrading Node version from 0.8.20 to 0.10.2"

Comment: @JoshC. He is not running js code in IE. Its a server side jQuery. i.e browserless jquery in node.js

Comment: @ThomasW-B Can you show us more codes? Try installing the dependencies into the folder %project%/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/> npm install node-XMLHttpRequest  Link: [node-XMLHttpRequest](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni what about the other link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151834/javascript-xmlhttprequest-result-are-always-undefined

Comment: @JoshC. both of those are browser based, I think the problem I'm having has something to do with nodejs and the server side implementation of jquery

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni I've tried installing that node module and the error is still there.

Comment: @ThomasW-B: As you said you are on `Linux`. I tried on the same OS with `node v0.10.2` and just done with `Windows 7 64-bit` as well. So, please consider showing your codes in more detailed view...

Comment: @JoshC.: The other [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151834/javascript-xmlhttprequest-result-are-always-undefined) you pointed is code which they are running in browsers.

Comment: @ThomasW-B: Can you update your question with details of the output which you will see after you execute command `npm install jquery`?

Comment: @ThomasW-B Also do an npm initiate on an empty directory. Then do `npm install jquery` in the empty directory and add the output from the install to your question. I think this problem is a problem with `XMLHttpRequest` not being setup properly. Which is a different issue. (Not related to node.js versions) So, remove `after upgrading Node version from 0.8.20 to 0.10.2` from your question's title

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni I think you are correct, I cannot work on this at the moment but once I am able to I will follow your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: I have the same error using node 0.6

Comment: I have the same problem on Node 0.10.0.

Comment: For those of you with this problem, check my answer, it should help you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this:

Same error here...
I don't know what I'm doing, but I changed the **node-jquery.js fourth-fifth row's** and it's start working :)

old:

```
if(window == null ) {
    window = require('jsdom').jsdom().createWindow();
```

new:

```
if(!window || !window.document) {
    window = require('jsdom').createWindow();
    window.document = require('jsdom').jsdom();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't *actually* have a prototype object in Node server code, it's all stored in the much nicer [**__*proto*__**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)  object and you should be using [Object.create/defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

What exactly are you trying to do? Run an ajax query with Node? If so, you should be using [Nodes http.request](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_event_request)

An example could be:

```
require('request').post({
    "uri"     : "http://example.com/",
    "headers" : {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    "body"    : "hello=world"
},
function(e,r,b){
    // e = errors, r = response and b = returned body
    console.log(b,r.statusCode));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an issue with the jsdom module that node-jquery depends on.  It appears that this is a known issue, and that it has been fixed, but not published to npm yet.

Check it out: https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery/issues/52